# Remote access to Linux graphical session with opensource software behind router without the need for PAT/NAT configuration

Tags: linux, software-rec, open-source

I use anydesk on my Linux behind my ISP router and my Dad PC also using anydesk on Linux behind his ISP router.

I'd like to use an opensource software to gain remote access to the Linux graphical session that does not need complicated network setting (especially on the remote side) like anydesk.

EDIT0: I want to know how Anydesk works so I can find a software that can traverse NAT routers without the need for "touching" the remote side ISP's router settings.

Do you know an opensource software that can do that ?

Comment: Do your routers support VPN? If so, that's a solution

Comment: It seems you have excluded all the options. Without PAT/NAT or VPN you're not going to get anywhere

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not possible to answer it

Comment: @roaima Maybe Anydesk uses VPN because I just found an option that was already checked `Create VPN tunnels`. Anydesk might be using a VPN tunnel to traverse NAT routers. I just removed the VPN restriction in the title of my question. I guess my router supports VPN because Anydesk works.

Comment: Do the two routers themselves provide VPN endpoints, so you can connect them together across the Internet? That would be your easiest solution

Comment: @roaima After investigating Anydesk with a `netstat -natup | grep anydesk`, it appears it is listening to `7070/tcp` and `50001/udp` and is connected to a Anydesk relay on https : `relay-12e4567c.net.anydesk.com.`

Comment: @roaima I found these two Anydesk web pages : [Anydesk firewall#Ports-and-Whitelist](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/firewall#Ports-and-Whitelist) and [Anydesk settings#connection](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/settings#connection)

Comment: It seems you really just you want to use Anydesk. So use it. Problem solved

Comment: @roaima Nope, I want to know how it works so I can find a software that can traverse NAT routers without the need for "touching" the remote side ISP's router settings. You didn't give any software name so far. Is there any ?

Comment: Each endpoint establishes a connection _outbound_ through the local router to a "well known" server managed by Anydesk and is registered there. Each endpoint has a unique identifier. When two endpoints try to connect to each other the connection is initially established through the Anydesk server. It probably tries to help the two endpoints talk directly to each other, with each one attempting to initiate an outbound connection to the other. This can sometimes fool routers enough for the connection to establish directly and the Anydesk server can remain just as a controller

Comment: @roaima Thanks a lot for your help and explanation :+1: